# Best way to request synchronization when offline

Tags: html, offline, service-worker

I'm developing a web app that need work on-line and when the coonection is not available, so i would like to say how the best way to synchronization my requests when on-line again. I see some things about Service Workers, but i don't know if it is the best.

Comment: Please make sure you read this and try to improve your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely use service workers for this use case!

The particular solution will depend on your specific needs (service workers are pretty generic).

A possible approach would be a "request deferrer", like the one implemented in the [ServiceWorker Cookbook](https://serviceworke.rs/request-deferrer.html). In this solution, while the user is offline, requests to the server are queued and, when the user goes back online, the queued requests are actually executed against the server.